# Use of "would" (conditional) in 'If you go to the jungles in Africa, you would see a lot of animals.'

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Can one use "would" as the conditional in this sentence?

Example: If you go to the jungles in Africa, you **would** see a lot of animals.

Comment: I think it's:  *If you **were** to go, you **would** see.*  OR  *If you go, you **will** see.*

Comment: Well, an open conditional could be: *"If you go to the jungles in Africa, you will see a lot of animals."* A corresponding modally remote conditional could be: *"If you went to the jungles in Africa, you would see a lot of animals."*

Answer (score 3):

> If you go to the jungles in Africa, you would see a lot of animals.

Despite the two  dogmatic answers, and similar comments, (as of my writing) that state that this sentence is incorrect, I'm loath to force English speakers to speak according to paradigms found in textbooks.

*Yes*, it is an observable fact that the way native speakers  signal an irrealis condition is to use a past tense in the if-clause (protasis) and a "past tense"  modal such as *would* or *could*  in the main clause (apodosis). Thus, in this case,  we would expect

> If you *went* to the jungles in Africa, you *would see* a lot of animals.

...and that the way to signal an open condition, one that may be possible or actually the case, then we would not use the past tenses:

> If you *go* to the jungles in Africa, you *will see* a lot of animals.

However, spoken or actual  English is not so crystal clear or uncluttered as textbook English.

Thus, this true "mixed conditional" construction

> If you *go* to the jungles in Africa, you *would see* a lot of animals.

could be uttered in such a context as the following:

> So *you'd like* to see a lot of animals, *would ya*? Is that what *you'd like*? Well, *if you go* to the jungles in Africa, like you're planning on doing–I mean you've bought the tickets and you're leaving within the month–(well *if you go*), *you'd see* a lot of animals, (since that's what *you'd like* to see).

The protasis is stated as an open condition because it's an actual possibility and the apodosis with *would*, because that's the "mode" or mindset that the speaker is in for  each proposition of the sentence. He might also say

> Go to the jungles of Africa already, and you'd see a lot of animals (since that's what you'd like to see).

These two sentences seem natural enough to me and thus within the realm of possibility, whether they're  "licensed" by textbook forms or not.

Comment: It would help to add information about the registers in which you would (or would not) expect this construction. For example this is much more likely to be observed in informal spoken English than in formal written English.

Answer (score 0):

English has three types of [conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English) sentences.

> predictive (first conditional, or "conditional I": "**If** I **feel** well, I **will** sing")
>   speculative (second conditional, or "conditional II": "**If** I **felt** well, I **would** sing")
>   (third conditional, or "conditional III"
>   "If I **had felt** well, I **would have** sung").

*It is only the speculative type (second or third conditional) that causes the conditional **would** to be used.*

Use of *if* with the present tense means using **will** + infinitive

> If you go to the jungles in Africa, you **would** see a lot of animals. (incorrect)
>   If you go..., you **will** see... (correct)

Use of *if* with the past tense means using **would** + infinitive

> If you **went**..., you **would** see... (correct)

here is another good source of [the conditional](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm).